# Image Placeholder with Percentages?

Tags: html, css, image, placeholder, wireframe

Any idea if there is a way to use a placeholder with percentages? 
I know there is code that allows you to put pixel dimensions, but What about percentages instead? The code for the placeholder is img src="http://placehold.it/350x150". I am asking  because I want to put together wireframes, but I also want it to fit to whatever screen is used. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using place hold it thats just the end file dimension you can use css to change the size to anything you want

```
img{
 width:50%; /** Set to whatever you need **/
 height:auto; /** Retain image aspect ratio **/
}
```

**Optional**

Add `max-width`,`min-width` / `min-height`, `max-height` for more control

Comment: Oh, wow. I thought it would take more than that, but I guess it's just me over-analyzing things again. Thinking things are more complex than they have to be. Thanks.